# Trigger radioButton action via updatePanel when a radio is checked onLoad

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, radio-button, updatepanel

I have a asp.net Webforms form with multiple radio buttons.  On load I need to select (check) some of the radio buttons.  The issue is that the radio buttons that were checked will not trigger the UpdatePanel async functions when I re-select those radios.  However, if I do not select any of the radios onload the UpdatePanel will properly trigger when I re-select those radios.  It seems the UpdatePanel fails to bind the necessary javascript function to trigger the radio button update if it is checked during page load.  If anyone has any suggestions or recommendations to work around this issue I'd greatly appreciate it.  Thanks in advance.